# .attr("id") in jQuery 1.6.1

Tags: jquery, attr

I am using

`jQuery(something).attr("id")`

in jQuery 1.6.1 and seem to be getting issues with this - basically, it's returning blank ?

I thought all the issues with 1.6.1 resolved backwards compatibility etc for the `.attr` or ?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using? The `attr` function should work fine.

Comment: does the element something has an `id` at all? jQuery 1.6+ added `prop` witch is different from what you are doing, no matter what version of jQuery, to get hold of the id attribute of a DOM element it still is the way you are doing, but, if the element does not have an `id`, like `<table class="myTable">` it will always be blank!

Comment: @JamesAllardice @balexandre - my JS assigns the elements ID and then further on I extract the assigned ID - hence the reason I need the `id` attribute. This worked without any issues in 1.3.2 and 1.4.4 - so I'm confused why it's causing me issues now

Comment: Are you sure that "something" is right? I'm trying with http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js and it works.

Comment: @Tim: Can you show the HTML, the code that is setting the ID, and the code that is getting the ID?  There may be a problem in another spot, because `.attr` works fine in jQuery 1.6.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/384cP/

Comment: @rocket - changing to @raynos solution works - but in 1.6.1 - i seem to be getting errors [haven't tested in 1.6.0]

Comment: @Tim it is 1.6.1:  * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.1

Comment: Go this link http://www.meneame.net/story/estrategias-poder-desprestigiar-movimientos-sociales-caso and execute this on the browser: javascript:alert($(".comment-body").attr("id"))

Comment: @vtortola - yeah i'm using an array and from this array extracting a JS assigned ID. Using @raynos solution works - but this previously worked in jQuery 1.4.4 - but seems to render "undefined" in 1.6.1 :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `something.id` (if its a `HTMLElement`)

or `$(something)[0].id` (if it's a selector string)

Comment: thanks. for some reason in 1.6.1 - in my array - and when assigning the ID element further back in my JS code - this renders an error in 1.6.1 for me. Changing to your answer - `$(something)[0].id` - seemed to pass the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the selector you are using is returning an array of objects. In which case you need to do:

```
jQuery(something).each(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  //Do what ever you need to with each id
});
```

Or just select the first element.

Comment: Actually I've tried with a selector that returns an array of elements, and it shows the first.